# Error: DataTables warning: table id = example1 - Cannot reinitialize DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

Are you all right?

I'm having a problem and I need your help.

My application displays this error message: "DataTables warning: table id = example1 - Cannot reinitialize DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3".

I have read in some places that it is important to start "Datatables" only once, but could not find a good solution. I've tried it in many ways, but in most of them I miss the translation to my language (Brazilian Portuguese). My code is following.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you all in advance!

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example1').DataTable( {
        "oLanguage": {
          "sEmptyTable": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
          "sInfo": "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
          "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
          "sInfoFiltered": "(Filtrados de _MAX_ registros)",
          "sInfoPostFix": "",
          "sInfoThousands": ".",
          "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ resultados por página",
          "sLoadingRecords": "Carregando...",
          "sProcessing": "Processando...",
          "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
          "sSearch": "Pesquisar",
          "oPaginate": {
              "sNext": "Próximo",
              "sPrevious": "Anterior",
              "sFirst": "Primeiro",
              "sLast": "Último"
          },
          "oAria": {
              "sSortAscending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente",
              "sSortDescending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma descendente"
          },
          "select": {
              "rows": {
                  "_": "Selecionado %d linhas",
                  "0": "Nenhuma linha selecionada",
                  "1": "Selecionado 1 linha"
              }
          }
        }, 

        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ],
        language: {
            buttons: {
                copyTitle: 'Copiado para área de transferência',
                copyKeys: 'Pressione <i>ctrl</i> ou <i>\u2318</i> + <i>C</i> para copiar os dados da tabela para a área de transferência. <br> <br> Para cancelar, clique nesta mensagem ou pressione Esc.',
                copySuccess: {
                    _: '%d linhas copiadas',
                    1: '1 linha copiada'
                }
            }
        }

    } );
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#example1 thead tr').clone(true).appendTo( '#example1 thead' );
    $('#example1 thead tr:eq(1) th').each( function (i) {

        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Procurar '+title+'" />' );

        $( 'input', this ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            if ( table.column(i).search() !== this.value ) {
                table
                    .column(i)
                    .search( this.value )
                    .draw();
            }
        } );
    } );

    var table = $('#example1').DataTable( {

        orderCellsTop: true,

    } );
} );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, you initialize `$('#example1').DataTable(.....` twice.

Here

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example1').DataTable( {
  .....
```

and

here

```
var table = $('#example1').DataTable( {

    orderCellsTop: true,

} );
```

So errors says you cant do that, you should take that `orderCellsTop: true` put in the first initialization process.

Comment: I did that, but then it stopped filtering by columns, which is a necessity for my application.

Answer (score 0):

If setting the `orderCellsTop` attribute in your first call to `DataTable()` is not an option, then you may have to destroy the existing table and initialize a new one.

First check if the table already exists with `$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable()` and if so, destroy it with `table.destroy();` and then create a new one with whatever attributes you need.

All this is explained on the [page linked in the error](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3).